# sublime text 3 - console - how to open a file

Tags: sublimetext3

I would like to open files to edit from the sublime text 3 console (which appears on ctrl+`)

I have tried

```
open [filename]
```

but it always gives syntax error on the last character of filename. I have tried enclosing name in quotes.

Also, I would like to know if I can execute shell commands directly from it's console

Comment: It is a Python console.

Comment: Yeh, the same question... Want just copy file names and open them by pasting as parameter to some internal command. standard file open dialog is horrible for development tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the command:

`sublime.active_window().open_file("filename.txt")`

It's a bit ugly, but probably could be scripted/automated somehow (to have a shortcut for instance).

Comment: how would you automate that? +1 for solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you **really** want to open files from the console (it's much easier just to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>), the following command will open the file picker dialog:

```
window.run_command("prompt_open_file")
```

There is no command to open a specific file from the console.

If you are interested in learning more about Sublime's Python API, [look here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

Comment: well, I didn't want to pick the file in the first place..thanks though.

Comment: @YashGupta what exactly are you trying to do, then?

Comment: what I wanted to do was open console with ctrl+` type open file/i/want and be done. In the open file dialog, I cant type the path to file (like "../some-script" ...it gives invalid file name error).

Answer (score 1):

The console in the Sublime Text Editor is a python console.

To execute shell commands, you need to import os, and then execute them:

```
import os
os.system("date")
```

Comment: any way to open files from it? sublime must be having some kind of api..considering we can install packages from it

Comment: Why do you wish to open files from the sublime python console? What are your exact intentions?

Comment: well intention is to work faster. Some packages open read me file after installing in sublime...so that was the inspiration.

Comment: This point isn't to have shell in Sublime, but to utilize Sublime' object model to quickly copy a filename from opened text, and paste it to the console, as some argument to some internal command, and open it just by hitting enter.